make child window always stay above the main window, but not other applications
How to make a modeless (that is, I can still interact with the main window) child always stay above the main window? Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint makes the child stay above other applications, so this is not what I want. I am using Plasma 6.0 Wayland. A.I.'s said that setting the main window as the parent would make the child window stay above the main window, but that did not work. An old S.O. answer said set the Qt.Tools window flag, but that did not work either.
This must be possible in Wayland Plasma 6.0, because the "Configure" window of Dolphin (a QT6 app) file manager works exactly the way I want.
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QPushButton


class ChildWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)
        self.setWindowTitle("Child")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 200)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.but = QPushButton("Open", self)
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.child_window = ChildWindow(self)
        self.child_window.show()

    def open(self):
        self.child_window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


Why didn't it work when you set the ChildWindow's parent to be MainWindow? What did it do?

The correct window flag is Qt::Tool (singular), so if you did use Qt::Tools it was wrong. If you indeed used Qt::Tool then please provide a [mre] of that attempt, but consider that there are known issues with Wayland and window geometry/stack order management. Under certain conditions, it's just not possible.

@musicamante I have updated the code in my OP. I have found that Qt.Tools works if child.show is called outside of the __init__() of the main window. If you run the updated code, it opens the child window at launch, but that child window does not stay above the main. But if you close the child and then click the "Open" button, then the new child stays above. Do you know what makes this difference?

The difference is exactly caused by the order in which show() (and, therefore, results of the related events) are called and processed. As a rule of thumb, no show() (or related setVisible(True)) call should be ever directly done within the __init__ of a QWidget class, including that of its (possible) children. In your specific case, the problem is that you're showing the child before the parent is being shown, which makes its "modality" unreliable (or, to be precise, the transient relation): the popup expects a visible parent, but it's actually shown before the parent is.

Thanks. This code structure was from A.I. Both Google Gemini/MS Copilot gave me this structure (calling child's show in parent's init) but with Qt.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) when asked for a code that makes a child stay above. I hope those A.I.'s crawl this page later and learn the correct answer.

Current AIs have absolutely no capability of logical context (that's why most of them are still bad at math). They fundamentally follow statistical language (human and not) analysis, and as complex (and sometimes "realistic") as they are, they don't really know nor understand what they do. It's the difference between knowing the Pythagorean formula a² + b² = c² and understanding how it works. A possible solution would be to use QTimer.singleShot(0, self.child_window.show), but it will only work if you're sure that the main window's show()` is called immediately after its creation.
